# Validate ICD-10-CM

Tags: c#

Has anyone written a validation (regex or otherwise) for ICD-10-CM?

I'm not interested in the trivial solution (3-7 alphanumeric), I'd like to know how incorporation of the 7th digit requirement was handled.

Comment: ICD-10-CM are standardized diagnosis codes used in medical care.  This code set replaces ICD-9 codes starting next year.

Comment: Very poor question. If it wouldn't have an open bounty, I would vote for close as *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow"*

Comment: I4V - your ignorance of the topic doesn't mean it is a poor question.  the question seeks expertise from a subject matter expert who knows what icd-10 is and how to validate.  it is a non-trivial programming matter.

Comment: this question is no different than asking about a regex for a phone number or zip code.  I think the down votes come from ignorance of the subject.  which if I need to explain what icd-10 is, the responder is not qualified to answer.

Comment: It could help to post some data to serve as a representative set. Also, showing what attempts you have made could open the solution up to more people to answer.

Comment: Upvoted, just because an individual doesn't understand the question , it doesn't make the question bad, in fact ICD10CM is a valid tag. However more details would certainly allow more people to suggest variety of solutions

Comment: @mson a responder experienced in pattern matching or data cleansing is better qualified to answer than someone who knows ICD10CM but only knows a bit about pattern matching - otherwise you wouldn't need to ask. Data professionals encounter new formats all the time but know or find techniques to deal with them. Please post some links to the definition of ICD10CM and examples.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos i disagree.  there are nuances to icd10cm that require experience to understand.  there is an optional 7th character that may or may not be present that requires certain codes to be padded with x.  i DO NOT want inexperienced responses.  if you don't know what it is, you shouldn't be responding.

Comment: Anybody wanna see what's in the ICD-10 CM, full text search it here...
http://www.mediware.com/rehabilitation/lp/icd-10-lookup-tool/

Answer (score 7):

I didn't write a regular expression for ICD-10-CM but I've written a lookup engine. You can do the same by parsing the [official XML file](ftp://ftp.cdc.gov/pub/Health_Statistics/NCHS/Publications/ICD10CM/2014/) into a SQL database, and searching the database for the code (if no results are found, code is invalid). Unfortunately, I cannot post my code here due to various NDAs but it should be trivial to do the same. The benefits are that you'll only get valid codes (and not codes that "look" like ICD-10-CM but are invalid, as you would with regex).

Alternatively (and I wouldn't recommend it) you can do a full-text search on the XML file itself on top of a simple regular expression, but it'll be buggy (from experience).

Comment: How did you incorporate the optional 7th digit and buffering with Xs?  A lookup does not seem optimal.

Comment: Consider `T36.0x1a` which is a valid code but `T36.0x7a` which is not. Regex has no way of determining which is a valid code beyond verifying the format. I don't know what your requirements are, but if you're just looking to validate the format, then you can determine the length of the string and use different regex's depending on the length range. Verify the position and count of the decimal point and

Comment: make sure that there's no "u" and that the first digit is alpha and everything else is alphanumeric. If x's are present they need to be in the 5th or 6th place. Etc. You don't need to put everything in a regex; several if statements will do the job. You're going to need a lookup beyond that, which shouldn't be a problem (once you've parsed into an SQL database, it's relatively fast); we've used lookups in an enterprise environment for many months without problems. Anything beyond that you're probably trying to micro-optimize.

Comment: there are around 70k codes, loading initially takes a time. i dont think loading it into application is wise,  if only validating , i suggest one may use sql like select count(*) from icdtable where code='userinput'. subsequent validation should be accurate because it is mandatory to use these codes in medical docs and Billing. I found the codes in FY15_Tabular.xml and icd10cm_order_2015.txt,  which is available at http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/icd/icd10cm.htm .

Comment: pls. read 'mandatory' in above comment as 'mandatory in our workplace'

Answer (score 6):

I just wrote a regular expression for all 2016 ICD10 codes:

```
/^[A-TV-Z]\d[0-9AB](?:\.([\dA-KXZ]|[\dA-KXZ][\dAX-Z]|[\dA-KXZ][\dAX-Z][\dX]|[\dA-KXZ][\dAX-Z][\dX][0-59A-HJKMNP-S]))?$/
```

This regex assumes the dot is present after the third character when it is supposed to be; the CDC distributes the code lists with dots omitted.

In the research I've done regarding ICD10 code structure, not all the rules and pitfalls are documented.  This regex was constructed according to the codes that actually exist, because documentation found online for ICD10 structure doesn't tell the entire story.

First character is alpha, except U.

Second char is numeric.

Third char is numeric, A, or B (these letters were recently added).

Dot for codes longer than 3 characters (not referred to as a character in any descriptions of code rules).

Fourth char is numeric or letters ABCDEFGHIJKXZ.

Fifth char is numeric or letters AXYZ.

Sixth char is numeric or X.

X is as a placeholder when appearing as the fourth, fifth, or sixth character (but never the last character).

Seventh char is more complex than any reference suggests.  A,D,s is for sequela. Certain other sets of codes have their own extensions; for bone fractures these are ABCDEFGHJKMNPQRS, where ADS still express sequela but may confer additional info.  Codes exist that use digits 01234 in this position.

Laterality is not straightforward at all.  Documentation states that 1 == right, 2 == left, which is usually true.  However, 3 == bilateral, 9 == unspecified (5th char) and 0 == unspecified (6th char) are not always true.

There are many codes where laterality is represented in conjunction with something else, often which limb.  In these codes, left, right, unspecified is expressed using 1,2,3; 4,5,6; 7,8,9 to represent the other factor.  A doubly unspecific code using 0 may also be present.

Furthermore, the character expressing laterality is not always the last character of the first six.

The descriptions of some lateral codes suggest an additional "other" side.

Comment: Can you just add the dot in after the third character in the CDC list, or is dot placement more complex than that?

Comment: @EamonnM.R. The Dot is always between the 3rd and 4th character, or always omitted for 3 character codes.  Whenever ICD10 codes or the scheme is discussed or explained, the dot is always included; it's considered part of the code and should be displayed with it.  Why they distribute the codes files without it is beyond me.

Answer (score 4):

ICD10 is actually a tree of codes where usable codes are the leaves, with each node containing metadata that applies to itself and all descendents.

As said in other answers, some codes may look like an ICD10 code but are actually invalid.  However, they do include a flat list of all codes at

http://www.cdc.gov/nchs/icd/icd10cm.htm

This list of codes does not contain the UTF-8 encoded characters on ~50 codes, 
such as

```
H81.01 Ménière's disease, right ear
```

with non-ascii characters, but does contain descriptions of all `69823` *usable* codes. So you can tell right away that the maximum possible code cardinality of `26*10*10*10*10*10*26` is much greater than `69823` so regexes are right out.

In order to get all of the 7th character information, parsing of the XML and expanding based on 'rules' is required. And if you are looking for metadata on each of the codes, the flat code file does not have it. You will have to parse the XML for that metadata (or use an API, etc.)

An example is best:

```
  <diag>
    <name>H40.11</name>
    <desc>Primary open-angle glaucoma</desc>
    <inclusionTerm>
      <note>Chronic simple glaucoma</note>
    </inclusionTerm>
    <sevenChrNote>
      <note>One of the following 7th characters is to be assigned to code H40.11 to designate the stage of glaucoma</note>
    </sevenChrNote>
    <sevenChrDef>
      <extension char="0">stage unspecified</extension>
      <extension char="1">mild stage</extension>
      <extension char="2">moderate stage</extension>
      <extension char="3">severe stage</extension>
      <extension char="4">indeterminate stage</extension>
    </sevenChrDef>
  </diag>
```

In your XML parsing, to correctly get the 7th character, you must parse the string `One of the following 7th characters is to be assigned to code H40.11 to designate the stage of glaucoma` and expand the code `H40.11` to each `<extension>` under the `<sevenChrDef></>`. So with the above example, you will get each of the codes:

```
H40.11X0 Primary open-angle glaucoma, stage unspecified
H40.11X1 Primary open-angle glaucoma, mild stage
H40.11X2 Primary open-angle glaucoma, moderate stage
H40.11X3 Primary open-angle glaucoma, severe stage
H40.11X4 Primary open-angle glaucoma, indeterminate stage
```

The `X` is a 'placeholder' to ensure 7 character code length.

It gets worse...

Consider the code branch starting with `T64`:

```
<diag>
<name>T64</name>
<desc>Toxic effect of aflatoxin and other mycotoxin food contaminants</desc>
<sevenChrNote>
  <note>The appropriate 7th character is to be added to each code from category T64</note>
</sevenChrNote>
<sevenChrDef>
  <extension char="A">initial encounter</extension>
  <extension char="D">subsequent encounter</extension>
  <extension char="S">sequela</extension>
</sevenChrDef>
<diag>
  <name>T64.0</name>
  <desc>Toxic effect of aflatoxin</desc>
  <diag>
    <name>T64.01</name>
    <desc>Toxic effect of aflatoxin, accidental (unintentional)</desc>
  </diag>
  <diag>
    <name>T64.02</name>
    <desc>Toxic effect of aflatoxin, intentional self-harm</desc>
  </diag>
  <diag>
    <name>T64.03</name>
    <desc>Toxic effect of aflatoxin, assault</desc>
  </diag>...
```

`T64` is not a leaf node and is therefore not billable. However, it still has 7th character metadata. This means that you must apply or 'multiply' *each* child code by its `<sevenCharDef>`, or `A`, `D` and `S`, obtaining the codes:

```
T6401XA Toxic effect of aflatoxin, accidental (unintentional), initial encounter
T6401XD Toxic effect of aflatoxin, accidental (unintentional), subsequent encounter
T6401XS Toxic effect of aflatoxin, accidental (unintentional), sequela

T6402XA Toxic effect of aflatoxin, intentional self-harm, initial encounter
T6402XD Toxic effect of aflatoxin, intentional self-harm, subsequent encounter
T6402XS Toxic effect of aflatoxin, intentional self-harm, sequela

T6403XA Toxic effect of aflatoxin, assault, initial encounter
T6403XD Toxic effect of aflatoxin, assault, subsequent encounter
T6403XS Toxic effect of aflatoxin, assault, sequela
```

We will hopefully get permission to reprint/supplement the ICD10 codes in JSON format where each code has explicit metadata, but until then this is your best bet.

If all you need is to determine validity of an ICD10 code, just load up the first column of the flat file (separated by `\r`).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that ICD10 codes can be three to seven characters. You can add the ^ and $ as required for start of line and end of line requirements.

This one works for 7 characters

```
[A-TV-Z]\d[0-9AB]\.[\dA-KXZ][\dAX-Z][\dX][0-59A-HJKMNP-S]
```

This one works for 6 characters

```
[A-TV-Z]\d[0-9AB]\.[\dA-KXZ][\dAX-Z][\dX]
```

etc. The finished regex that looks for a 7, then 6 etc. to three characters provided here:https://regex101.com/r/VYPHXZ/3 on a working test site, and below in text.

The problem is that regex was never designed to handle what amounts to an expanding op code. But it can be done. To go from seven to three the regex is a chain of OR groupings. Just in case your're not familiar with a capture group, anything in ()'s will by default be a capture group. By using ?:, I have chosen to override this behavior. When looking for an 'expanding-code' always look for the longest one first, and then in descending order in length.

```
^(?:(?:[A-TV-Z]\d[0-9AB]\.[\dA-KXZ][\dAX-Z][\dX][0-59A-HJKMNP-S])|(?:[A-TV-Z]\d[0-9AB]\.[\dA-KXZ][\dAX-Z][\dX])|(?:[A-TV-Z]\d[0-9AB]\.[\dA-KXZ][\dAX-Z])|(?:[A-TV-Z]\d[0-9AB]\.[\dA-KXZ])|(?:[A-TV-Z]\d[0-9AB]\.)|(?:[A-TV-Z]\d[0-9AB]))$
```

Answer (score 1):

Update for COVID diagnosis codes:  The letter "U" is valid as of 2020.

Answer (score 0):

Having implemented ICD9 a few times, and having seen ICD10, as far as I know ICD (9 or 10) has never been something you can completely check for with a regex. Sure, theoretically, if you know all language "keywords" you can implement a DFA for it, but it isn't practical.

I wrote a fast lookup function (it was for mobile devices in 2006, so SQL engine was a bit slow back then). Just read the ICD database into a hash table at bootup, and keep it there, the hash lookup is approximately as fast as a DFA.

FWIW I still have the source for the EMR engine (and own the license) but its in C++. Its about as easy to just describe the approach (as above).